# system of nonlinear equations can be solved in Maple, but not in sympy

Tags: python, sympy, maple

I am new to sympy and enjoyed the pythonic syntax. However, I encountered a problem that can't be solved by sympy but can be easily solved in Maple.

So, I have following system:

```
0.0165 * exp( -2.0405-0.33*b-0.5*n)+0.031 * exp(-4.164-0.62*b-0.5*n)=k*p
0.025 * exp( -2.0405-0.33*b-0.5*n) +0.025 * exp(-4.164-0.62*b-0.5*n)=5*k
2*p=p*b+5*n
```

I need to solve `b`,`n` and `k` in terms of `p`. I can easily solve this in Maple, but using sympy, it takes forever and crashed at the end for exhausting the RAM. Maple can provide exact symbolic solutions.

The sympy code I used is `solve([eq1,eq2,eq3],[b,n,k])`

Thank for you any help!

Comment: Please `s/5k/5*k/`  and  `s/2p/2*p/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the rational=False flag:

```
>>> print filldedent(solve([eq1,eq2,eq3],[b,n,k], rational=False))

[(-3.44827586206897*log((-0.000335859591913345*p +
0.00110833665331404)/(2.24927535168052e-5*p - 0.000139455071804192)) +
2, 0.689655172413793*p*log((-0.000335859591913345*p +
0.00110833665331404)/(2.24927535168052e-5*p - 0.000139455071804192)),
(0.000335859591913345*((-0.000335859591913345*p +
0.00110833665331404)/(2.24927535168052e-5*p -
0.000139455071804192))**1.13793103448276 +
2.24927535168052e-5*((-0.000335859591913345*p +
0.00110833665331404)/(2.24927535168052e-5*p - 0.000139455071804192))**
2.13793103448276)*exp(-0.344827586206897*p*log((-0.000335859591913345*
p + 0.00110833665331404)/(2.24927535168052e-5*p -
0.000139455071804192))))]
```

Comment: Thanks! the the result seems consistent with Maple. Could help explain what you did here? Where do I add `rational=False` flag? and what does `filldedent` mean? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, copy and paste error. I updated to show the use of 'rational'. The filldedent is just a printing utility function defined in sympy (from sympy import filldedent) that shortens printed lines and makes copy/paste more convenient.

Comment: @smichr  I tried your solution, but got empty list [  ] as the answer!

Comment: Make sure you are using the current version of SymPy.